# Java no longer works after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, java

I'm trying to run a .jar file on my computer. It worked in version 11.10, but in 12.04 now, I get a fatal error message from Iced Tea Web, saying it cannot parse the JNLP file. I've tried installing other Java clients but had no success, they don't even appear on the 'open with' list.

Answer (score 6):

Oracle Java 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 x64:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install oracle-jdk7-installer`

I think due to 12.04 still in Beta theres no source list or something. I don't really understand everything yet, still learning myself.

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Test if Java is Working:

- http://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp

From:

- http://christiansons.net/mike/blog/2012/03/oracle-java-7-on-ubuntu-11-10-12-04/